# NGINX unexpected behaviour with location directive and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a NGINX configuration file to serve a Website with static files and via a development Server.

static -> http://localhost:8080

dev webserver -> http://localhost:8080/dev

There are several other services which I bind to different location directives.

Here is a snipped of the configuration file.

```
...
upstream qgis {
   server qgis-spcluster_server:80;
}
...    
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/build;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    auth_basic "Zugangskontrolle";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location /dev/ {
    proxy_pass http://web_app/;

    auth_basic "Zugangskontrolle";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location /static/ {
    proxy_pass http://web_app/static/;
}

location /qgis/ {
    proxy_pass http://qgis/;
}

location /apex/ {
    proxy_pass http://apex/apex/;
    auth_basic "off";
}

...
```

Everything works as expected until i open the URL to get the static files. After that all other URLs leads to the static files.

- http://localhost:8080/apex -> Apex Service
- http://localhost:8080 -> static Website
- http://localhost:8080/apex -> static Website

For me everything looks ok, but indeed something is not ok.

The Basic_Auth produce another unexpected behaviour.

- http://localhost:8080 -> basic auth -> success -> static website
- http://localhost:8080/apex -> basic auth -> it is not possible to get rid of the pop up

So in the moment I'm a little bit clueless how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried now several things, but nothing really worked well. So I decided to create a second server block for all location directives which are problematic with my current setup.

Probably this is not the best solution, because I have still no idea why I get these problems. But it works now and that counts for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the trailing `/` from your location directives or provide `/` when you access them.

Nginx looks for the longest prefix match location. When you access http://localhost:8080/apex, it's routed to `/` because `/apex/` is not the prefix of `/apex`

Documentation of `location` is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: That sounds valid to me. Do you have any idea, why nginx is asking me to enter a Username and Password for the apex endpoint?  This only happen after I opened the URL with the static Website. Is this probably related to my first issue?

Comment: I think it's the same issue. If you still have problems please provide more details. Thx.

Comment: Let me test a few things. I have the feeling that maybe the service-worker I'm using causes some of the problems. If I enter http://localhost:8080/apex/ I still get on the static Website.